# Configuring exim's outgoing e-mail address

Tags: php, email, debian, exim4

I forgot how I set it. I have two websites and I send the e-mail through my second site. Here's my `/etc/exim4/passwd.client` file:

```
*.google.com:noreplyn@firstsite.com:password
*.google.com:noreply@secondsite.com:password
```

I'm sending mail through PHP's `mail()` function with the following headers:

```
$headers = 'From: no-reply <noreply@secondsite.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: noreply@secondsite.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
```

But I am getting this header on my client's email:

```
from:    no-reply firstsite.com
reply-to:    secondsite.com
to:  apathetic012@gmail.com
```

How do I properly set a custom outgoing e-mail address for exim?

> PS: I'm using a smarthost (Google apps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your envelope `From`.

```
mail($recipient, $subject, $body, $headers, '-f noreply@secondsite.com');
```